# Looking to speed up loop including pandas operations

Tags: python, performance, pandas, for-loop

I need help speeding up this loop and I am not sure how to go about it

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit

n = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({0:np.random.rand(n),1:np.random.rand(n)})

def loop():
    result = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index,columns=['result'])
    for i in df.index:
        last_index_to_consider = df.index.values[::-1][i]
        tdf = df.loc[:last_index_to_consider] - df.shift(-i).loc[:last_index_to_consider]
        tdf = tdf.apply(lambda x: x**2)
        tsumdf = tdf.sum(axis=1)
        result.loc[i,'result'] = tsumdf.mean()
    return result

print(timeit.timeit(loop, number=10))
```

Is it possible to tweak the for loop to make it faster or are there options using numba or can I go ahead and use multiple threads to speed this loop up?

What would be the most sensible way to get more performance than just simply evaluating this code straight away?

Comment: Looping over a data-frame is not ideal, **especially** if you use `.loc[...] = `, because there's a lot of overhead per loc-based assignment (it is designed to be used for bulk assignment, not row-by-row). You could speed this up by accumulating into a `list` object, and assigning that all at one time in the end.

Comment: Although, at a scale of `n=1000`, that will not have an appreciable effect. Rather, you should explain what your algorithm is doing, and try to use vectorized operations to accomplish it. That would be where you see the most gains, before delving into `numb`/Cython

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of compute happening per iteration. Keeping it that way, we could leverage underlying array data alongwith [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for the `squared-sum-reductions` could bring about speedups. Here's an implementation that goes along those lines -

```
def array_einsum_loop(df):
    a = df.values
    l = len(a)
    out = np.empty(l)
    for i in range(l):
        d = a[:l-i] - a[i:]
        out[i] = np.einsum('ij,ij->',d,d)
    df_out = pd.DataFrame({'result':out/np.arange(l,0,-1)})
    return df_out
```

Runtime test -

```
In [153]: n = 1000
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame({0:np.random.rand(n),1:np.random.rand(n)})

In [154]: %timeit loop(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.43 s per loop

In [155]: %timeit array_einsum_loop(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.61 ms per loop

In [156]: 1430/5.61
Out[156]: 254.9019607843137
```

Not bad for a **`250x+`** speedup without breaking any loop or *bank*!

Comment: Congratulations !

Comment: @B.M. I bet this is on not breaking a bank :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, the ultimate speedup with numba :

```
import numba
@numba.njit
def numba(d0,d1):
    n=len(d0)
    result=np.empty(n,np.float64)
    for i in range(n):
        s=0
        k=i
        for j in range(n-i):
            u = d0[j]-d0[k]
            v = d1[j]-d1[k]
            k+=1
            s += u*u + v*v    
        result[i] = s/(j+1) 
    return result

def loop2(df):
    return pd.DataFrame({'result':numba(*df.values.T)})
```

For a 2500x+ factor.

```
In [519]: %timeit loop2(df)
583 µs ± 5.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you for sharing it. I acutally used numba already, but still used `np.roll`, which is probably not ideal.